# Prove that $\sqrt[k] \frac{1}{k+2} \to 1$ by squeeze theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I wish to show that for $k \to \infty$:
$$\sqrt[k] \frac{1}{k+2} \to 1$$ by  the squeeze theorem.
I was thinking about the following upper bound: 
$$\sqrt[k] \frac{1}{k+2}  \leq \sqrt[k] \frac{k}{k+2}=\sqrt[k] \frac{1}{1+ \frac{2}{k}} \leq \sqrt[k] \frac{1}{1}  \to 1 $$

**I am having trouble with finding a lower bound, I think $\sqrt[k] \frac{1}{k+k}$ is too loose of a bound, I maybe need something stricter.**

Comment: Why do you think $k+k$ in denominator is too loose of a bound?

Comment: I do not see how $\sqrt[k]\frac{1}{2k} \to 1$

Comment: The answer below proves that

Comment: True. I understand it as well now.  In the limit we get $\frac{1}{2^0}=1$ and $\sqrt[k]{k}=1$, very neat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $k\geq 2$
$$
\left(\frac{1}{k+2}\right)^{1/k}\geq \left(\frac{1}{2k}\right)^{1/k}=\frac{1}{2^{1/k}}\times\frac{1}{k^{1/k}}\to1\times1=1
$$
as $k\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Another squeezing argument follows from 
$$
\liminf \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \leq\liminf \sqrt[k]{a_k} \leq \limsup\sqrt[k]{a_k} \leq \limsup \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}.
$$
Letting $\displaystyle a_k=\frac{1}{k+2}$ implies
$$
\liminf \frac{k+2}{k+3} \leq\liminf \sqrt[k]{\frac{1}{k+2}} \leq \limsup\sqrt[k]{\frac{1}{k+2}} \leq \limsup \frac{k+2}{k+3}.
$$
Consequently, $\displaystyle \lim\sqrt[k]{\frac{1}{k+2}} \to 1$.